# Twilio Client JS - get socket error on re-register

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twilio-client/fkpebhikbddijbkjkdielllenlgbmalc) that uses the Twilio client JS library. I have the session length set to 1 hour, to allow the extension to receive as well as place calls. Each time the registration token expires, I re-register and everything seems to be ok. If I look in Chrome Dev Tools at the background page, in the console I see:

```
[Device] Received error: 
Object {code: 31205, message: "JWT Token Expired"}
```

Which is the error I trap to know when to re-register. Each time I do this, right before that error I see:

```
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

Repeated an average of 40 times, then it appears my extension re-registers OK. About every 5th cycle of this, I see a short burst of:

```
Object {code: 31204, message: "Cannot register. Token not validated"}
```

And probably 5-6 times a day see:

```
Object {message: "Unable to determine account.", code: 401, rt.message: "error"}
```

My main question is am I in a race condition somewhere? I determine when it's time to re-register by handling the `Twilio.Device.error` event and then calling `Twilio.Device.destroy()` Then waiting 3 secs  and regenerating the JWT and calling `Twilio.Device.setup()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm Megan with Twilio.

It does sound like this could be a race condition. Without seeing exactly what you're running, I can take a couple of guesses as what you might try to fix.

1. Your callback errors might not be in the right order.
2. If you don't already have it, you'll want to [terminate the active connection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#disconnect-all) with `Twilio.Device.disconnectAll()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm already calling disconnect all. I think I have narrowed the issue down to: When token expires, Twilio.Device.error() fires, and in there i check the error, and call Twilio Device.setup(). Then, Twilio.Device.offline() fires, and I'm handling that by also calling setup. when i do this, i never get a ready event back, so i dont know what state the device is in. should i NOT be doing anything in the Device.offline() handler? Heres a gist of the flow: https://gist.github.com/nikmartin/ded28eeee54e212beff7